# very long string as a response of web service

Tags: java, android, string

I am getting a really long string as the response of the web service I am collecting it in the using the `StringBuilder` but I am unable to obtain the full value I also used `StringBuffer` but had no success.

Here is the code I am using:

```
private static String read(InputStream in ) throws IOException {
    //StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(1000);
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    String s = "";
    BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader( in ), 1000);
    for (String line = r.readLine(); line != null; line = r.readLine()) {
        sb.append(line);
        s += line;
    } in .close();

    System.out.println("Response from Input Stream Reader >>>" + sb.toString());
    System.out.println("Response from Input S >>>>>>>>>>>>" + s);
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also split the string in array of strings in order to see all of them

```
String delimiter = "put a delimiter here e.g.: \n";
String[] datas=sb.toString().split(delimiter);

for(String string datas){
System.out.println("Response from Input S >>>>>>>>>>>>" + string);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The `String` may not print entirely to the console, but it is actually there. Save it to a file in order to see it.

Comment: upvote for the right answer but it's the marked answer that helped me thanks a lot for the quick response

Answer (score 1):

I do not think that your input is too big for a String, but only not shown to the console because it doesn't accept too long lines. Anyways, here is the solution for a really huge input as characters:

```
private static String[] readHugeStream(InputStream in) throws IOException {
    LinkedList<String> dataList = new LinkedList<>();
    boolean finished = false;
    //
    BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in), 0xFFFFFF);
    String line = r.readLine();
    while (!finished) {
        int lengthRead = 0;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        while (!finished) {
            line = r.readLine();
            if (line == null) {
                finished = true;
            } else {
                lengthRead += line.length();
                if (lengthRead == Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
                    break;
                }
                sb.append(line);
            }
        }
        if (sb.length() != 0) {
            dataList.add(sb.toString());
        }
    }
    in.close();
    String[] data = dataList.toArray(new String[]{});
    ///
    return data;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        String[] data = readHugeStream(new FileInputStream("<big file>"));
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(StackoverflowStringLong.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (OutOfMemoryError ex) {
        System.out.println("out of memory...");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

System.out.println() does not print all the characters , it can display only limited number of characters in console. You can create a file in SD card and copy the string there as a text document to check your exact response.

```
 try
                {
                      File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Responsefromserver");
                      if (!root.exists()) 
                        {
                          root.mkdirs();
                      }
                      File gpxfile = new File(root, "response.txt");
                      FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(gpxfile);
                      writer.append(totalResponse);
                      writer.flush();
                      writer.close();
                  }
                  catch(IOException e)
                  {
                             System.out.println("Error:::::::::::::"+e.getMessage());
                      throw e;

                  }
```