# XmlPullParser with base64encode tag

Tags: android, smack, xmlpullparser

I am parsing xml packet using XmlPullParser. I am able to parse base64encode tag. My issue here is "I am not able to read full base64encode data. Only part of it is able to read".

```
boolean done = false;
 while (!done) {
        int eventType = parser.next();

        if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
            String elementName = parser.getName();
            String namespace = parser.getNamespace();


             if(elementName.equals("vCard") && namespace.equals("vcard-temp"))
            {
             }

            // Otherwise, see if there is a registered provider for
            // this element name and namespace.
            else {
                Object provider = ProviderManager.getInstance().getIQProvider(elementName, namespace);
                if (provider != null) {
                    if (provider instanceof IQProvider) {
                        iqPacket = ((IQProvider)provider).parseIQ(parser);
                    }
                    else if (provider instanceof Class) {
                        iqPacket = (IQ)PacketParserUtils.parseWithIntrospection(elementName,
                                (Class)provider, parser);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
            if (parser.getName().equals("iq")) {
                done = true;
            }
        }else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT){
            String xx = parser.getText();
            System.out.println("binaval "+ xx);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Man, that if-else-if chain is hurting my eyes. Anyway, the code you posted does not show anything related to b64 encoding or decoding. Do you have any exception? Are you sure the string has been fully downloaded?

Comment: I have encoded image using base64.

Answer (score 1):

[very long string as a response of web service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13086131/very-long-string-as-a-response-of-web-service)

see this answer here sometimes for the very long string it doesn't work mine was the same case when I posted this question.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this problem. Please share with me

Comment: have you seen the link try this you may see the full base64 string

Comment: Assigning value to String won't show full string sometimes.But it will be assigned full string retrieving from base64